# XZDIO: unpacking of archive failed on file /opt/gluu-server-2.4.4.2/var/lib/rpm/Packages;5841179d: cpio: read failed - No such file or directory

Tags: rpm, rhel7, gluu

I am trying to install gluu server on an RHEL 7.2 server that does not have access to internet. Here is what I have done so far:

1. Download the rpm from internet
2. Transfer to SIT using winscp
3. Run rpm -i -vv gluu-server-2.4.4.2-1-1.rhel7.x86_64.rpm using root

But I get the following error:

> XZDIO: 261724 reads, 2212069840 total bytes in 62.814077 secs error:
>   unpacking of archive failed on file
>   /opt/gluu-server-2.4.4.2/var/lib/rpm/Packages;5841179d: cpio: read
>   failed - No such file or directory

have you come across such an issue before or any idea how to go about fixing this?

Comment: Hmmm ... what is in that *.rpm? It looks like you have an rpmdb within that rpm, .(because of the path you listed). Also check that you have enough disk space: rpm can report misleading errors when it runs out of disk space

Comment: Also: how big is the *.rpm file.? The reported no. of bytes is larger than 0x7ffffff (the largest signed integer)

Comment: @JeffJohnson, the .rpm filesize is about 770 MB. i have downloaded it more than twice to make sure its not a corrupted/broken copy.

Comment: Based on that path, it seems to be some kind of `chroot` or container-ized OS install. It sure sounds like it is corrupted, but I thought RPM had checksums in the file. You can test the file with `--test`. To see if it is corrupted, in a temporary directory you can extract it `rpm2cpio XXX.rpm | cpio -div`. I've also seen similar errors if it is the wrong OS, e.g. attempting a CentOS7 RPM install onto C6.